# Mono - Could not find a 'Sub Main' in ''

Tags: .net, vb.net, mono

I started a new solution (with multiple projects) and am trying to get it to build.  Initially I was getting an internal compiler error and thought maybe it had to do with MySql, so I removed all references to MySql.  Now I am getting the error "Could not find a 'Sub Main' in ''".  I have made sure that all of my projects have a Main subroutine like this:

```
Public Shared Sub Main()
End Sub
```

2 out of the 7 projects will compile.  I don't know what makes these projects different from the others, and the error message isn't very helpful.  Any experience with this one?

Answer (score 2):

In VB.Net the `Main` method is almost always declared within a `Module`.  This code does not look like it has the `Main` method in a `Module` as the `Shared` would cause a compilation error.  Try putting it into a module and specifying the name of the module as the startup one to the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest checking your Module also.  I utilize modules frequently to tie multiple projects together.  They use the sub Main in much the same way as a form would utilize the load event.